# Problem on rank of jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

> Let $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \Bbb{R}^3$ be a $C^1$ function satisfying Lipschitz condition. Let $J_f(x)$ be the jacobian of $f$ at $x$. Let $S=\{x: \mbox{ rank } (J_f(x))=2\}$. Is
> $S$ connected and compact?

I have no idea how to proceed. Please give me some hint or suggest me a book.

Comment: Hint: think of linear transformations. In this case, the set S is very obvious.